# Pass string to rubocop as a file

Tags: python, git, bash, unix

I am writing a git-hook in python that lints files pushed to the repository and rejects the push if the files don't pass linting requirements. I have already written a similar hook for php using php code sniffer and the code looks like this:

```
php_cs = subprocess.Popen(['phpcs', '--standard=' + self._standard], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = php_cs.communicate(input="file contents".encode('utf-8'))
```

This code works for php_cs, but so does:

```
cat file.php | phpcs
```

which as I understand it is all the python code is doing. I want to do something very similar for ruby using [RuboCop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop).

Using very similar python code to the phpcs the rubocop version looks like:

```
  rubo_cop = subprocess.Popen(['RuboCop'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  out, err = rubo_cop.communicate(input="file contents".encode('utf-8'))
```

the output in this case looks like:

[image]

This indicates that rubocop does not understand this input in the same way that phpcs understands which is why:

```
 cat file.rb | rubocop
```

does not work for rubocop

My question how can I pass a string to the command so that it treats it as a file?

Comment: Can you run it in the directory with the files? The usage section of the `rubocop` page says it defaults to scanning all local files. If that doesn't work then you probably need to use `xargs` (or similar) to convert standard input to command line arguments.

Comment: @EtanReisner This is githook runs on the remote repository so the files are not directly stored there, I need to be able to use git to show the file contents at specific revisions.

Comment: You can try using Process Substitution in bash (`rubocop <(git-command-that-spits-out-file-contents)`) but that may not work if rubocop expects a "real" file as argument.

Answer (score 3):

Try `cat file.php | xargs rubocop`

This is the pre-commit script I have for my rails projects
https://gist.github.com/qr8r/70510a0bc0cb54fd8427

Comment: This link is not accessible. Is that removed?

Comment: Updated the link :)